# Trying to publish object to Kafka using Spring cloud stream with Functional(Supplier) model

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, stream, cloud

I am trying to publish object to Kafka topic using spring cloud stream with functional model. Here is the code snippet for my requirement.

### Controller:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/publish")
public void publish(@RequestBody SampleObject obj) {
    service.publish(obj);
    log.info("Published Data {} successfully", obj.toString());
}
```

### Service Class:

```
@Bean
public Supplier<Object> publish(SampleObject obj) {
    return () -> {
        log.info("posting data to kafka topic {}", obj);
        return obj;
    };
}
```

My requirement is I need to send request object from controller to service and publish that object to Kafka topic.

NOTE: I don't want to go with deprecated model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using `StreamBridge`.

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_using_streambridge

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class WebSourceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebSourceApplication.class, "--spring.cloud.stream.source=toStream");
    }

    @Autowired
    private StreamBridge streamBridge;

    @RequestMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public void delegateToSupplier(@RequestBody String body) {
        System.out.println("Sending " + body);
        streamBridge.send("toStream-out-0", body);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it helps. Publish data part is done and would like to see the best approach for read data from topic ?